# add more data-attributes to split icon in jquery mobile listview

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

i am working in a webapp where i am using listview of jquery mobile...

Here, just want to customize the split icon on the right hand side of every list line...

But want to do this with the use of data-attributes like `data-split-shadow="false"` and `data-split-stroke="false"`, so that the shadow and the white circle stroke on the icon will not be shown and only the grey background and icon will display...

I have attached a demo for this...
http://jsfiddle.net/FkGz8/

Just like that,

```
<ul class="ui-icon-alt" data-role="listview" data-inset="false" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-theme="d" data-split-stroke="false" data-split-shadow="false">
```

Can it be possible?

Comment: Sorry can you please clarify you question? You want to use some other icon and you don't want to have shadow and the white circle stroke on the icon (but without use of attributes)?

Comment: no, i want to have same icon or default jqm ones and don't want to have shadow and white circle stroke on the icon...

Comment: You will need to tell me what is data-split-stroke="false"? Is it a white circle around an icon?

Comment: this... http://i.imgur.com/eNC1E5d.jpg

Comment: Then my example should be it. Take a notice that it is build to accommodate listview from your example. So if you have another listview with different class or id then remove .ui-icon-alt from my css and replace it with correct class or id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/rQtmC/

**CSS :**

```
.ui-icon-alt li .ui-li-link-alt .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn {
    width: 18px !important;
    height: 18px !important;    
    border-width: 0 !important;
}

.ui-icon-alt li .ui-li-link-alt .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn, .ui-icon-alt li .ui-li-link-alt .ui-btn-inner .ui-btn .ui-btn-inner .ui-icon {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 !important;
}
```